# Groovy way to remove file extension?

Tags: groovy, file-extension

I'm wondering if there is a "Groovy" way to remove the file extension from a filename.

The current solution relies on the apache commons io package:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

String filename = '/tmp/hello-world.txt'
def fileWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(filename)
```

Comment: unless you want to get rid of the whole commons.jar - what is wrong with using a (battle-hardened) library function?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
filename[0..<filename.lastIndexOf('.')]
```

To remove everything after the last `.` in the String.

Or the slightly prettier:

```
filename.take(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

***NB:*** *if a file haven't an extension it will be not matched*

Comment: In the example given you can use any substringing method you like but in the general case there may not be an extension at all and in some cases directories contain a ".", hidden directories in linux for example.

Answer (score 3):

May be overkill in this case but I tend to treat a lot of the commons classes as mixins

```
String.metaClass.mixin org.apache.commons.io.StringUtils
String.metaClass.mixin org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils
etc
```

This then allows you to

```
String filename = '/tmp/hello-world.txt'
def fileWithoutExt = filename.removeExtension()
```

Which ones I mixin depends on the requirements of the script but I tend to use this pattern a lot. It enables me to easily use methods I'm used to using without all the static class or import references.